# Google blogger web domain

Tags: blogger

Im pretty new to this to just learning by trial and error. I created my blog on Google Blogger.
I also bought a domain from Go daddy and paid for hosting too. When I entered the web domain which I changed to www.whereshallieat.co.uk and it redirects to the blogspot one I get the error message

This blog is open to invited readers only

http://whereshallieat.blogspot.com/
It doesn't look like you have been invited to read this blog. If you think that this is a mistake, you might want to contact the blog author and request an invitation.

You're signed in as pwfaiza92@gmail.com - Sign in with a different account

and before it said welcome to go daddy. Im not quite sure how to fix this just thought it would be good enough to add the domain in i paid for ....

thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: oh sorry.. I thought it was all IT related questions

Answer (score 0):

Open blogger.com >> Sign in >> **Settings** >> **Basic**

and under "**Permissions**" you'll find **Blog Readers** option.

Just select "**Public**" (Your blog is open to all readers by default)

You may get the solution... Cheers!